# Fine Grained access management with AWS Cognito and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I have several groups of users (which have there own identity pool in Cognito) which have different rights on Endpoints in API Gateway. I manage the Access rights using the IAM Roles. For example I have this policy for one identity pool:

```
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1467885818000",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "apigateway:Invoke"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:891841139854:api-id/*/*/usergroup/*"
    ]
}
```

Now I want to have access rules, based one individual identities. The reason is, that I have resources which my only be changed by the user who "onws" the resources (or are listed as being allowed to access the resource).

Can I somehow user IAM for this?
My Idea is something like this:

```
"Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:891841139854:api-id/*/*/<my-user-name>/*"
    ]
```

So this way every user can only the Endpoints with his username (and this username can than be forwarded to lambda, which can be sure that the given user has the right to perform the action).

Is this possible? If not how would I configure fine grained access?

Comment: Which integration are you using with API Gateway ? HTTP proxy, Lambda functions or AWS Service Proxy ?

Comment: Different ones. But mostly lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IAM conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition) to check the user identity. Have a look a [this blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies) to see more examples. It should look like this:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "apigateway:Invoke"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:891841139854:api-id/*/*/<my-user-name>/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:<identity-pool-id>",
            "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": "us-east-1:<identity-id>"
        }
    }
}
```

But I would recommend you to proceed differently.

In the API Gateway integration configuration, you can [pass the Cognito pool and identity to the lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference). Then, in the Lambda, you know the identity of the caller (and you can call the [Cognito API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeIdentity.html) if you need more information about the user identity).

You will be able to create endpoints that might look like `GET /user/me/my-resource` and will **perform actions depending on the Cognito identity of the API Gateway caller**. You will not need to create *x* endpoints and policies for each identity in your Cognito identity pool.